# How can I install *.apk from jenkins on real device with Appium and run tests written in python?

Tags: android, python, jenkins, appium

I have a BDD test automation framework with cucumber and python with behave for android mobile app testing.
I want to set up a jenkins job wherein I can Start the appium server and launch the android mobile app and trigger the test execution.
Can someone please help on this ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Install Jenkins in your system visit the Jenkins url in browser. 
In my local I access Jenkins using "http://localhost:8080"

Step 2: Tap "New Item" > "Freestyle Project" > 'OK'

Step 3: Scroll to 'Build' section > Add Build Step > 'Execute Shell' and enter the below commands:

```
#!/bin/bash --login -x
appium &
sleep 5s
```

[image]

Step 4: Click on 'Build Now'.

Step 5: Open the running job > 'Console Output' to ensure Appium server is running.

The following text should be displayed in console logs:

```
[Appium] Welcome to Appium v1.6.4
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

Step 6: All the test scripts should be placed inside 'workspace' directory of Jenkins. My scripts are in this location:
    /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/appium-android/

Step 7: I use pytest, so my command is as follows:

```
cd $WORKSPACE
pytest /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/appium-android/tests/listings/test_listing_create.py
```

For behave run the command accordingly.

to answer this:
*launch the android mobile app*

Appium should take care of launching the app

*Ensure you have all dependencies installed in Jenkins machine, like Python, Appium python client, Appium server, behave etc*